# How to make vertical menu icon lines

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with making a menu icon that instead of three horizontal lines has three vertical lines that change into X when clicked... like on this website [example](https://designcanada.com/)...

So far my best attempt got me this far...
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/weinde/27btg1eL/9/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=27btg1eL)

I need some help making the animation work and making the lines vertical...

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="hamburger" id="menu-button">
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="menu-button_lable">Menu</span>
</div>
```

**My SCSS:**

```
#menu-button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width              : 60px;
  height             : 45px;
  -webkit-transform  : rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform     : rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform       : rotate(0deg);
  transform          : rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition : .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition    : .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition      : .5s ease-in-out;
  transition         : .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor             : pointer;
  .line {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 25px;
    background: #d3531a;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    &:nth-child(1) {
      top                      : 12px;
      -webkit-transform-origin : left center;
      -moz-transform-origin    : left center;
      -o-transform-origin      : left center;
      transform-origin         : left center;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      top                      : 18px;
      -webkit-transform-origin : left center;
      -moz-transform-origin    : left center;
      -o-transform-origin      : left center;
      transform-origin         : left center;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      top                      : 24px;
      -webkit-transform-origin : left center;
      -moz-transform-origin    : left center;
      -o-transform-origin      : left center;
      transform-origin         : left center;
    }
  }
  .menu-button_lable {
    font-size: .7857142857rem;
    letter-spacing: .06em;
    line-height: 1.3;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 2.2rem;
    margin-top: 0.75rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
  }
  &.open span {
    &:nth-child(1) {
      -webkit-transform : rotate(45deg);
      -moz-transform    : rotate(45deg);
      -o-transform      : rotate(45deg);
      transform         : rotate(45deg);
      top               : 6px;
      left              : 8px;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      width   : 0;
      opacity : 0;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      -webkit-transform : rotate(-45deg);
      -moz-transform    : rotate(-45deg);
      -o-transform      : rotate(-45deg);
      transform         : rotate(-45deg);
      top               : 24px;
      left              : 8px;
    }
  }
}
```

**and my JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nmenu-button').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just hide it and replace with another element (which contains vertical lines) which is previously hidden?

Comment: @VipulSharma it doesent look as good as an animation...

Comment: You probably want to use your own code, but you can check this https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/Atyop and add `rotate(90deg)` instead of 0deg (wrapper it's not animated).

Comment: You will get better answers if you convert your code to stack snippet. (icon next to image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below.
Additional CSS added for each line to position it correctly when active.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#menu-button", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
});
```

```css
#menu-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.line {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 25px;
  background: #d3531a;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger .line:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
/* Added */
.hamburger.is-active .line:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
  top: -9px;
  left: 9px;
}

.hamburger .line:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
}
/* Added */
.hamburger.is-active .line:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hamburger .line:nth-child(3) {
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
}
/* Added */
.hamburger.is-active .line:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
  top: -9px;
  left: 1px;
}

.menu-button_lable {
  font-size: .7857142857rem;
  letter-spacing: .06em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: absolute;
  left: 45px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hamburger" id="menu-button">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="menu-button_lable">Menu</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you... with minor ajdustments to your code i got what I needed. I'm accepting your anwser

Answer (score 0):

It is just a pure css hamburger menu icon which does not require a click event triggering, simple hover will work. To form the "X", I reduced opacity of the **.strip.two**. rotated, and translated **.strip.one** & **.strip.three** to get the "X". If you want you can add click event in which all you have to do is add and remove classes as per your requirement.

```css
    .menuIcon{
      display:inline-block;
      width:2em;
      height:2.2em;
      
    }
    
    .strip{
      width:3px;
      height:2em;
      display:inline-block;
      background:black;
    }
    .menuIcon:hover{
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    
    .menuIcon:hover .strip.two{
      opacity:0;
    }
    .strip.one,.strip.two,.strip.three{transform-origin:50% 50%;transition:all 100ms ease-in-out;}
    .menuIcon:hover .strip.one{
      transform:rotate(45deg) translateY(-0.5em);
    }
    .menuIcon:hover .strip.three{
      transform:rotate(45deg) translateY(-0.5em);
    }
```

```html
<div class="menuIcon">
  <span class="strip one"></span>
  <span class="strip two"></span>
  <span class="strip three"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be very helpfull if you add some more information to provide what you have done and why. Just posting an example doesn't help anyone. Beside that I don't think your solution is working well.

Comment: It is just a pure css hamburger menu icon which does not require a click event triggering, simple hover will work. and Questioner has a vertical menu icon. so I reduced width and increased height. To form the "X" , reduced opacity of the second strip and rotated, and translated first and the third elements to get the "X". If Questioner wants can add click event in which all he has to do is add and remove classes as per their requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hamburger').click(function(e){
    $(".hamburger").toggleClass("is-active");
  });
});
```

```css
  #menu-button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width              : 60px;
  height             : 45px;
  -webkit-transform  : rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform     : rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform       : rotate(0deg);
  transform          : rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition : .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition    : .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition      : .5s ease-in-out;
  transition         : .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor             : pointer;
  }
#menu-button .line {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 25px;
    background: #d3531a;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
#menu-button .line:nth-child(1) {
      top                      : 12px;
      -webkit-transform-origin : left center;
      -moz-transform-origin    : left center;
      -o-transform-origin      : left center;
      transform-origin         : left center;
    }
#menu-button .line:nth-child(2) {
      top                      : 18px;
      -webkit-transform-origin : left center;
      -moz-transform-origin    : left center;
      -o-transform-origin      : left center;
      transform-origin         : left center;
    }
#menu-button .line:nth-child(3) {
      top                      : 24px;
      -webkit-transform-origin : left center;
      -moz-transform-origin    : left center;
      -o-transform-origin      : left center;
      transform-origin         : left center;
    }

.menu-button_lable {
    font-size: .7857142857rem;
    letter-spacing: .06em;
    line-height: 1.3;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 2.2rem;
    margin-top: 0.75rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
  }
#menu-button.open span { }
#menu-button.is-active span:nth-child(1) {
      -webkit-transform : rotate(45deg);
      -moz-transform    : rotate(45deg);
      -o-transform      : rotate(45deg);
      transform         : rotate(45deg);
      top               : 6px;
      left              : 8px;
    }
#menu-button.is-active span:nth-child(2) {
      width   : 0;
      opacity : 0;
    }
#menu-button.is-active span:nth-child(3) {
      -webkit-transform : rotate(-45deg);
      -moz-transform    : rotate(-45deg);
      -o-transform      : rotate(-45deg);
      transform         : rotate(-45deg);
      top               : 24px;
      left              : 8px;
    }
 

.line {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  background: red;
}
.hamburger{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.menu-button_lable{
 color:red;
 padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hamburger" id="menu-button">
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="menu-button_lable">Menu</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You do realise that that is exactly the same what i posted?... i need the thre lines to be vertical... all you did was include jQuerj in my fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

This is the style for vertical hamburger.

```css
.hamburger {
  width: 14px;
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.line::before,
.line::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 2px;
}

.line::after {
  right: 0;
}

.line::before {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="hamburger" id="menu-button">
  <span class="line"></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: and how can I animate the before and after element?